# ACF: custom fields and archive.php

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I know there are a lot of information about this problem - but i tried all that I could find, so I need a help

There is a simple case - I registered new post type and add tags:

```
add_action('init', 'add_video_type');
function add_video_type() {
$args = array(
'labels' => array(
'name' => 'Video',
'singular_name' => 'video',
'add_new' => 'Add new video'
),
'public' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt3',
'supports' => array('title'),
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
);
register_post_type('video', $args);
}
```

That post has a advanced custom field `<?php the_field('video_link'); ?>`
And yes, of course it works.
But, if I click on tag and go to archive page I take nothing.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
get_template_part( 'video', get_post_format() );
endwhile;?>
```

Ok, "how to take a custom field from other post":
That I tried:

```
<?php echo the_ID(); $variable = get_field('video_link', $post->ID); echo $variable; ?>

    <?php the_field('video_link', 'video'); ?> //video it's a page with loop
    <?php the_field('video_link', 123); ?> //id of video post
```

It's interesting, that "echo the_ID" work, of course work.
And interesting, that "the_field('video_link', 123)" work
But I can't merge them!

Comment: In arhive page `<?php the_field('video_link', the_ID()); ?>` returns nothing.
On simple page with wp loop that code returns "video_link" from post which ID I choose. I need such result at archive page too..

Comment: You need this in the loop?

Comment: Try using `<?php the_field('video_link', get_the_ID()); ?>`. The `the_ID()` function echoes the id, but `get_the_ID()` just returns it.

Comment: Doesn't work :(  `<?php the_field('video_link', get_the_ID()); ?>` returns nothing, but `<?php the_field('video_link', the_ID()); ?>` returns value "3325" - post id.

Comment: Sorry - `<?php the_field('video_link', get_the_ID()); ?>` returns nothing on archive page and returns "video_link" on page with loop. `<?php the_field('video_link', the_ID()); ?>` on archive page returns just a id value "3325" and return "3325video_link" on page with loop.

Comment: Mark, yes in loop, but on archive.php page. Now it look like: `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );  get_template_part( 'video', get_post_format() ); endwhile;?>`